# How to create Outlook's new mail window with attachement in?

Tags: c#, email, .net-3.5, outlook, outlook-2003

I'd like add to my app function allowing sending email via Outlook same as eg Adobe Reader does.
So after pressing email button I'd like to see Outlook's native 'new mail' window with my document attached in.
Any idea how to archive that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not interop?

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/819398

Comment: I'm happy to go that way :) Any suggestion how to use it for that?

Answer (score 0):

Not quite a solution, but more of a hint: maybe creating an *.eml file with your attachment and opening it (as a new mail window) would help?